# How to evaluate the integral : $I=\int\frac{2-x+(x-1)\ln x-\ln^2x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate the integral: $$I=\int\frac{2-x+(x-1)\ln x-\ln^2x}{(1+x \ln x)^2}dx.$$

Help me, thanks :/

Comment: One observation is that the numerator factors as $(1-\ln x)(2-x+\ln x)$; according to Mathematica, $\frac{2-x+\ln x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}$ is integrable, and integration by parts works. But I don't immediately see how to integrate $\frac{2-x+\ln x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}$ nor the other resulting integral.

Comment: Looks a bit like the derivative of u/v where v = 1 + xln(x). Play with that a bit to find a suitable u.
Paul

Comment: How did @Paul commented with $1$ reputation? Was the rep requirement to comment finally abolished? :)

Answer (score 0):

The result is quite unimaginable:

According to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%282-x%2B%28x-1%29ln+x-%28lnx%29%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bxlnx%29%5E2,

$\int\dfrac{2-x+(x-1)\ln x-\ln^2x}{(1+x\ln x)^2}~dx=\dfrac{x-x\ln^2x+(x\ln x+1)\ln(x\ln x+1)}{x\ln x+1}+C$